# Symfony2 Forms - How to use parametrized constructors in form builders

Tags: symfony

I am learning to use Symfony2 and in the documentation I have read, all entities being used with Symfony forms have empty constructors, or none at all. (examples)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html Chapter 12 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

I have parametrized constructors in order to **require** certain information at time of creation. It seems that Symfony's approach is to leave that enforcement to the validation process, essentially relying on metadata assertions and database constraints to ensure that the object is properly initialized, forgoing constructor constraints to ensure state.

Consider:

```
Class Employee {
    private $id;
    private $first;
    private $last;

    public function __construct($first, $last)
    {  ....   }
}

...
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $employee = new Employee();  // Obviously not going to work, KABOOM!

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($employee)
            ->add('last', 'text')
            ->add('first', 'text')
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Should I not be using constructor arguments to do this?

Thanks

**EDIT :**  Answered Below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution:

Looking into the API for the Controllers "createForm()" method I found something that is not obvious from the examples. It seems that the second argument is not necessarily an object:

```
**Parameters**
    string|FormTypeInterface     $type  The built type of the form
    mixed                        $data  The initial data for the form
    array                        $options   Options for the form
```

So rather than pass in an instance of the Entity, you can simply pass in an Array with the appropriate field values:

```
$data = array(
    'first' => 'John',
    'last' => 'Doe',
);
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
    ->add('first','text')
    ->add('last', 'text')
    ->getForm();
```

Another option (which may be better), is to create an [empty data set](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/use_empty_data.html) as a default option in your Form Class.
Explanations [here](http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html)

```
class EmployeeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('first');
        $builder->add('last');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'empty_data' => new Employee('John', 'Doe'),
        ));
    }
    //......
}

class EmployeeFormController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new EmployeeType());
    }
    //.........
}
```

Hope this saves others the head scratching.

Comment: It's easy if you simply pass static strings. How to pass variables to the Employee's constructor?